# How can I find the source of received packets?

Tags: windows, networking

Is there a way to trace the source, or find where large numbers of packets are coming from in Windows?  Any recommendations on a program that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a packet by packet basis, you can check the source address field with a protocol analyzer like Wireshark, or you can view the over all connections with a tool like netstat or TCPView as @JKM mentions. you could then use a tool like dig, nslookup, and whois to determine info about the host connecting to you, or use tracert to determine one of the possible paths between them and you. technologies like NetFlow/NTOP, MRTG, and IDPSs like Snort can gather statistical information so you can determine what if any source is driving an unusual amount of traffic to your server, but these all require some network infrastructure to set up.

This information however may not really provide you the IP address of the actual host. technologies that proxy/tunnel connections (web proxies, darknets (TOR, I2P, etc), ssh relays, vpns, etc) generally rewrite the source IP in each packet to provide their own, so that replies get relayed back through the proxy. Nation-states and ISPs have some capability to see enough of the picture to sometimes locate the actual source, but for most residential users, this will not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

[TCPview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) can show you the source of packets to your computer. However, it needs to be running first and it tracks the data coming in, it cannot show history.

Answer (score 0):

You can install very powerful packet sniffer [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (formerly known as Ethereal).

Wireshark will show you exact breakdown of your network traffic. However, it can only show traffic that comes to or from your computer, not from other computers.